# how to transform frequency domain into time domain

Tags: matlab, time, fft, ifft, time-frequency

I had created a 3 three different frequency signal and filter out the signal i don't want. But when i using ifft in matlab, it shows a wrong graph.How to transform my frequency domain spectrum back into my 3 second time domain graph? Below my code is as below:

```
clc
clear all
Fs = 8192;
T = 1/Fs;                                             
%create tones with different frequency
t=0:T:1;
t2=1:T:2;
t3=2:T:3;

y1 = sin(2*pi*220*t); 
y2 = sin(2*pi*300*t2);
y3 = sin(2*pi*440*t3);                          

at=y1+y2+y3;


figure;
plot(t,y1,t2,y2,t3,y3),title('Tones with noise');

[b,a]=butter(2,[2*290/Fs,2*350/Fs],'stop');
e=filter(b,a,at);
et=(ifft(abs(e)));
figure,
plot(et)
```

Comment: you wipe out the phase information when you do `abs(ffs(..`

Comment: hmmm...i do not get what you means

Comment: I see you editted the question and took it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is now, `et` is in the frequency domain, because of the fft. You don't need to fft. just `plot(e)` and you'll get the time domain filtered waveform. Yo can check the filter performance in the freq. domain by fft though, just

```
plot(abs(fftshift(fft(fftshift(e)))));
xlim([4000 5000])
```

**Edit:**

Your code as it is written on the question has the following bug:  `at` has exactly 1 second of info in it (or 8192 elements). If you `plot(at)` you'll see the sum of frequencies alright, but they all `happen` in the same time. This is how to fix it:

```
clear all
Fs = 8192; % or multiply by 3 if needed
T = 1/Fs;                                             
%create tones with different frequency
t=0:T:3;

y1 = sin(2*pi*220*t).*(t<1); 
y2 = sin(2*pi*300*t).*(t<2 & t>=1);
y3 = sin(2*pi*440*t).*(t>=2);                          

at=y1+y2+y3;

[b,a]=butter(2,[2*290/Fs,2*350/Fs],'stop');
e=filter(b,a,at);
figure,
plot(t,e)
```

[image]

```
dt=t(2)-t(1);
N=length(at);
df=1/(N*dt);        % the frequency resolution (df=1/max_T)
if mod(N,2)==0
    f_vector= df*((1:N)-1-N/2);     % frequency vector for EVEN length vectors: f =[-f_max,-f_max+df,...,0,...,f_max-df]
else
    f_vector= df*((1:N)-0.5-N/2);   % frequency vector for ODD length vectors f =[-f_max,-f_max+fw,...,0,...,f_max]
end
freq_vec=f_vector;
fft_vec=fftshift(fft(e));

plot(freq_vec,abs(fft_vec))
xlim([0 1000])
```

[image]

Comment: but how to ifft back to time domain which is from 0 second to 3 second as i created before. My question is to filter 300Hz..so..i want to shows my signal without 300Hz in time domain..Do you know how to make it?

Comment: if i want to fully filter my 300 HZ? is it possible?

Comment: yup...u helps me alot..^^ reali thanks you so much. Anywhere, How to design the flter that can fully filtered the 300 Hz?

Comment: And what does it means by tis code "y1 = sin(2*pi*220*t).*(t<1); "...why the t is need to .*(t<1)?

Comment: If you just take down the bottom limit of your filter from 290 to 250, and run the code you'll kill almost all the 300 Hz contribution. You can basically play with the limits (290 and 350 Hz) until you optimize your filter...

Comment: Thanks natan...^^ And what does it means by tis code "y1 = sin(2*pi*220*t).*(t<1); "...why the t is need to .*(t<1)?

Comment: this is a logic condition that sets the condition `true` (or the value 1) for all the elements of `t` in the range t<1 and `false` (or 0) for the rest, thus making `y1` equal `sin(2*pi*220*t)` only at the range [0,1], and `y1=0` for the remaining range, [1 3].

Comment: hai natan, may i ask one qn? why after fft, my 220 frequency suppose appear at 220 part but it appear at 660 Hz there? all m frequency multiply by three?